# how to implement domain classes

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am developing a java-spring project that have domain classes(user,step,answer).Suppose the answer to the question is, step by step. Each step has its own text and image. One answer might be a several steps. A question has been answered by a specific user. Answer each of the separately stored in the database and also can be edit or remove from db. The best implementation for this example, how can it be?

```
 public class Step{
   private int step_no;
   private String text;
   private byte[] image;

   //setter and getter
 } 
 public class Answer{
   private int id;
   private question_id;
   private String user;
   private List<Step> steps;

   //setter and getter
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use an Object Relational Mapping tool such as JPA, Hibernate or, what fits better here, Spring Data. These tools will allow you to directly map your tables and columns into entities and attributes.

ORM works with both java annotations or xml configuration. For beginners I would suggest you use annotations.

The best way to map these classes would be for the User to hold a list of all the answers he has done and, at the same time, the answer will hold a list of all the steps that belong to it. Let me show you a quick example of how it could be done.

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<name in db>")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "<column name in db>")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "<column name in db>")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Answer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<name in db>")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    private Integer answerId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Step> steps;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Step:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<name in db>")
public class Step {

    @Id
    private Integer stepId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Answer answer;

    @Column(name = "<column name in db>")
    private Object image;

    @Column(name = "<column name in db>")
    private String text;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

You can always use simple JDBC instead of powerful ORM tools to create the DB queries, but it is definitely recommended to take a look to the javax.persistence.* package and start from there.

Comment: can you more explain Step class and variables that use in this class?thanks

Comment: Well, as you can see, each Answer is going to hold a list of one or more Steps. So, in each Step we need to reference the parent Answer. The image will be stored in the DB as a binary object, so Java will map it to an Object class. The String text can hold enough information for all the text required in the step. @ManyToOne is the bi-directional link between the Answers and the Steps. And make sure you replace the brackets with the actual column names in the DB

Comment: this section is ambiguous for me  "in each Step we need to reference the parent Answer" can you explain with example? thanks very much.

Comment: I think this link would provide the exact explanation to what you need: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany